# No sound or microphone on Lubuntu

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, lubuntu

This is my first time posting here, I usually avoid asking questions as much as possible, but this is severely beyond my scope.

I've recently converted a Chromebook Lenovo 100e to run on Linux, keep in mind i was new to linux at the point, anyway, I've tried installing Arch Linux,Puppy Linux and Lubuntu on the machine, Arch Linux absolutely refused to install if i did not prevent the installation of Pipewire or any other audio package, puppy Linux was a lost cause for getting audio. Lubuntu is the only one that successfully installed without any problems. I have followed everysingle thread and online tutorial to no avail, I will post all the information that is commonly asked for:-

```
 $ inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: mo-robo Kernel: 6.4.12-060412-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: LXQt 0.17.1 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Google product: Robo v: rev3
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Google model: Robo v: rev3 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: coreboot v: MrChromebox-4.20.1 date: 07/21/2023
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio
  Cluster
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.4.12-060412-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes


$ pacmd list-cards
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_0e.0>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 7
        properties:
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x91210000 irq 124"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:0e.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "5a98"
                device.product.name = "Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "0"
                device.description = "Built-in Audio"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        profiles:
                output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <off>
        ports:
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"


$ modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel 
insmod /lib/modules/6.4.12-060412-generic/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko.zst 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/6.4.12-060412-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko.zst 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/6.4.12-060412-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko.zst 
insmod /lib/modules/6.4.12-060412-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-hda-core.ko.zst 
insmod /lib/modules/6.4.12-060412-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-codec.ko.zst 
insmod /lib/modules/6.4.12-060412-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-sdw-acpi.ko.zst 
insmod /lib/modules/6.4.12-060412-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-dspcfg.ko.zst dsp_driver=1 
insmod /lib/modules/6.4.12-060412-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko.zst dmic_detect=0
```

I may have reached the wrong conclusion but is it safe to assume that the current multi-media card does not work with the current Linux kernel, when researching the audio card i stumbled upon this https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/18857/audio-firmware-and-user-guide-for-the-intel-atom-processor-e3900-series-intel-celeron-processor-n3350-and-intel-pentium-processor-n4200-on-yocto-project.html

I do not have enough Linux understanding to install this firmware or edit and burn a bios or the create a custom linux kernel image. I was wondering if there is anything that i ma be missing, I have tried all the solutions involved with Alsa, Pulseaudio and Pipewire, and editing Modprobe and other related files with absolutely no change, is it safe to assume that the problem is deeper than software incompatibility.

I have also tried re-intalling firmware-sof-signed and ubuntu-drivers-common, which just resulted in no updates happening because the firmware was up to date. Also note that I have updated the kernel using Mainline Kernels package to the newest Linux kernel, this has not helped.

Thanks to anyone who takes their time to read this and excuse me if I'm missing anything due to my in-experience.

**Update**

So I've been doing some research on ALSA project, IT seems that the card really isn't built into ALSA according to this [page](https://www.calel.org/pci-devices/alsa-device-list.html#Intel) and the PCI vendor device Code doesn't seem to have been added as a driver to ALSA. Further [research](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=d24ecf10e2) shows that it was never added to the kernel for some reason. Will research further solutions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThGE0.png)

if anyone knows how to add firmware to a kernel or has good resources on it please notify me.

Comment: You mention Lubuntu, but also show details of a 6.4 kernel being used, which is not a *supported* kernel stack option for any supported version of Ubuntu/Lubuntu. Ubuntu/Lubuntu 22.04 LTS GA kernel stack uses 5.15, with the HWE stack currently using 6.2; so your provided details don't match a Ubuntu system as I see it, and you gave few specifics.

Comment: To clarify the Kernel version, I was recommended to update the kernel just in case the kernel is having a problem identifying the sound chip, with the possibility that a more recent update would fix this.

I used Mainline Kernels package to update the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the drivers from [this](https://github.com/WeirdTreeThing/chromebook-linux-audio) repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/WeirdTreeThing/chromebook-linux-audio
cd chromebook-linux-audio
./setup-audio
```

Then **reboot**.